# Ignoring Header/Footer text when using TIKA

Tags: apache-tika, ikvm

I'm using IKVM in order to use the TIKA library in a .NET application.  I'm able to extract text but now I want to tell TIKA that I do NOT want the Header/Footer information.  TIKA case [TIKA-906](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-906) shows that the latest version now includes the header/footer text, but does not show how to exclude it.

I'm pretty much using the same code outlined [here](http://www.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2010/07/02/using-the-tika-java-library-in-your-net-application-with-ikvm).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to use a non-default content handler, and configure that to exclude the xml sections covering the header and footer. Did you try doing that?

Comment: I have not.  I'll look into it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'd suggest you give that a try, then update your question if that doesn't get you all the way

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with a custom content handler.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide complete solution for same. Will be helpful to many including me. Thanks.